# ?Porque cuando intento enlistar mis usuarios de la DB mediante un foreach no me los muestra en mi vista?

Tags: laravel, controller, model-view-controller

en mi vista solo me muestra el titulo: Bienvenido a la pag principal y no me muestra mis usuarios de mi foreach
[image: este es mi show.blade]

aqui tengo mis usuarios
[image: estos son mis usuarios que deseo mostrar]

estoy creando mi metodo index el cual quiero que me muestre todos mis usuarios
[image: este es mi controlado]

aqui estoy creando mi ruta
[image: esta es mi ruta y la cual hace uso del metodo index]

Comment: Varios comentarios: 1. El código va como texto, 2. En el controlador mandas '$user' pero en la vista tratas de iterar `$User` con mayúscula, 3. por otro lado en tu foreach deberías dar un alias distinto para la variable que te recuperará los valores por cada iteración, de tal modo que en lugar de `$User as $user`, en todo caso debería ser `$users as $user`, entendiendo que modifiques tu controlador y sea `$users = User::all();` lo que pongas

Comment: Además me parece tienes un error en la invocación de la propiedad `created_at` si no escribiste tal cual debe ir entonces te falta la letra d

Comment: **ya corregi mi foreach:**                                                                                
 `@foreach ($users as $user)
        User:      {{$user->id}} </br>
        Name user: {{$user->nombre}}</br>
        Created_at:{{$user->created_at}} 
    @endforeach `                                                                                              
      **y este es mi metodo index pero no me arroja nada en mi vista** 
  `public function index()
    {
        $users =User::all();
        return view('user.show', compact('users'));
    }`

Comment: ¿Segura que si hay datos para mostrar? y que los nombres de las propiedades son correctos

Comment: @victoriaPerezHernandez agrega eso a tu pregunta y por favor, el codigo va como texto

Comment: @JuanRivera perdon, es primera vez que subo una pregunta y estoy tratando de subir el codigo y los estoy separando por bloques pero aun asi no me deja guardar la modificacion :(